# Зона ответственности при проектировании

Tags: javascript, vue.js, проектирование

Есть структура:
**Сервис API** (оболочка для ajax c перехватчиком и подстановкой токена)
**Сервис авторизации** (вызов api по адресу, с передачей данных - список адресов по сути)
**Сервис уведомлений** (показывает окошко пользователю с сообщением)
**Хранилище**  (vuex)
**Компонент авторизации** (компонент vue)

Соответственно, html шаблон формы находится в компоненте авторизации. Компонент инициирует авторизацию, т.е. из компонента через метод дергается сервис авторизации - дай нам логин вот с этими данными.

```
AuthService.login(vm.data).then(...
```

Сервис авторизации дергает сервис API - вот данные, такой url - отправь.

```
async login(payload) {
    return apiClient.post("/auth/login", payload);
},
```

Сервис авторизации если ответ адекватный - возвращает ответ (resolve), а если пришел ответ в неизвестном формате - дергает сервис уведомлений и передает туда ответ(reject).

Далее вот непонятно. кто должен ждать ответа, и сохранять данные в хранилище - сервис авторизации или все же компонент. Т.к. после получения ответа - еще надо сохранить токен,  получить данные пользователя после сохранения токена, уведомить пользователя о результате, перенаправить его если надо на какую то страницу.

Мне почему то, хочется запихнуть это в компонент. Это же логика авторизации непосредственно. Но тогда непонятно для чего выделялся Сервис авторизации. Адрес можно и в компоненте тогда хранить.

> Хотя может потому что сервис авторизации завязан на API и чтоб при
> смене адресов не лазить по компонентам а заменить все в сервисах.

Если отправлять все в сервис авторизации, то слишком много телодвижений надо будет чтобы передавать данные в компонент для вывода ошибок в html. Да и тогда сервис авторизации должен знать что то о хранилище. Когда компонент о нем знает в любом случае. В общем чет я запутался.

Как вообще решать такие вопросы если нету в окружении более опытных коллег? Я понимаю что понимание приходит с опытом - но может есть какие то негласные правила, которые могут помочь как то определяться с зонами ответственности? Или где то есть что почитать по этим вещам?

Comment: Почему то приветствие удаляется из текста..

Comment: .. и правильно делается, т.к. для сути вопроса оно не существенно )